# How to determine End Of Life of cygwin 1.7.32 and cygwin 2.8.2

Tags: cygwin

i want to know the End Of Life of cygwin 1.7.32 and cygwin 2.8.2.
could you please help me on this.

Regards
Manikanta

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is a rolling Distribution.
Only the last version is the supported one.

Please also note that "cygwin 1.7.32" and "cygwin 2.8.2" are only referring to the core
shared library and not to the entire Distribution